# filtering not equal to null entries

Tags: php, sql

I have a column, which stores numbers with `null` permitted .

A sample entry in column `numbers`:

```
numbers :
123
null
null
546
null
```

How do I extract non-null entries in SQL?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `IS` operator

```
select numbers 
from your_table
where numbers is not null and numbers <> ''
```

Comment: still gives all the records in it , including null ones

Comment: Then the records are not null. Maybe `''`